# manipulate parameters from http post request with a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, http-post

i have a remote service, that sends an http post request, to the url of my application

```
http://www.mywebsite.it/testsms/mywebservice.asmx
```

in ISO-8859-1 with the following parameters:

```
type=POST&sender=393471234567&receiver=393477654321&text=Ciao+Mario+come+stai&encoding=ISO-8859-1&date=2011-05-20&time=10%3A32%3A32&timestamp=1305880352&smsType=standard
```

how can i get and manipulate the parameters with the webservice?
in alternative the remote service could send parameters by SOAP (WSDL). In this case, how can i get the parameters in c#?

Thanks in advance...